# Mental approximations of 1) log, 2) non-integer power

Tags: logarithms, approximation, mental-arithmetic

I am currently preparing for a interview that is notorious for asking mental approximations. Two example questions came up: 1) $\ln 514$ and 2) $3^{3.6}$.

What are some of the best ways to calculate these on the spot? For 1), my consideration was to use the change of base $\ln 514 = \log_2 514/\log_2 e \approx \log_2 512/0.7 = 90/7$, but even that seems like a bit of a stretch. For 2), my approach was to use $3^{3.6}>3^3\sqrt{3}\approx 27\times 1.7$, which once again seems like a stretch.

Does anyone have better/more efficient/creative ways of approximating these? Please share, thank you!

Comment: for natural logarithm, I would use $\ln 514 = \ln 5.14 + 2 \ln 10 \approx \ln 5 +2 \cdot \ln 10$. If you know that $\ln 10 \approx 2.3$, you can get pretty close approximation.

Comment: I would go $ln 514 \approx ln 512 = 9 ln 2 \approx 6.3$ (using your estimate of $ln 2$), which is easier than dividing anything by 0.7

Comment: ... and for the other one: $3^{3.6} = 3^3 \times 3^{0.6} = 27 * 27^{1/5} \approx 27*2=54$ because 27 is pretty close to 32 (considering that the gradient of $y=x^5$ is 80 at $x=2$)

Comment: What about working graphically ? With paper and pencil, you can sketch a reasonable $10^x$ curve between $0$ and $1$, and probably achieve accuracy better than $5\%$.

Comment: $\ln 2$ is about $0.7$, so $\log_2 e \approx 1/0.7$, and a good approximation to $\ln 514$ would be $9 \times 0.7 = 6.3$.  (The actual value is about $6.242$.)

Comment: For natural logs I'd memorize $\ln 2 \approx 0.7, \ln 3 \approx 1.1, \ln 5 \approx 1.6$ (or alternatively to that last one, $\ln 10 \approx 2.3$ or $\ln 20 \approx 3$).  It might help to remember $\ln (1+x) \approx x$ for small $x$ but that might be finer detail than you need.

Comment: I would explain how to compute $\ln(\alpha)$ using Newton's method for any $\alpha > 0$. First the problem is reduced to the interval $\alpha \in [1,2]$. Then I would use the best uniform approximation of degree $1$ to initialized the iteration. Since the initial guess is fantastic, convergence is swift. Obviously, the man asking the question is going to protest because you are teaching him to fish instead of giving him a fish.  Answer him: "We either have a pocket calculator which can do basic arithmetic or civilization as we know it has fallen and we have bigger problems".